# nodejs web application problem with localStorage on Samsung s10

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a web application on nodejs using localstorage for storing the device id. It works fine on every devices except a Samsung s10 (it works fine on Samsung s8). I don't know if this is an android problem or any kind of incompatibility with localStorage.

It stores the data correctly, but the next day Localstorage is deleted. It has disabled auto clean options, but still not working.

I'm using chrome, but I have the same problem on firefox.

the code is very simple

```
//set
localStorage.setItem('device_id', res.device_id);

//get
localStorage.device_id
```

could it have any kind of incompatibility or any kind of method for make it works?

Comment: Why are using `localStorage.device_id` instead of `localStorage.getItem('device_id')` ?

Comment: hum certanly, but I have just test it with localStorage.getItem('device_id') and still not working

Comment: it seems to be the same https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_getitem.asp